# An Italian table, is it in fact Arabic?

Tags: etymology, loan-words

The other day I stumbled upon the Arabic word طاولة "tawila".

It occurred to me that it in fact sounds quite close to Italian "tavolo".

Is this just coincidental or was the word loaned in either direction at some point in time?

Comment: According to Italian dictionaries, "tavolo" comes from Italian "tavola", which comes from Latin "tăbula", which has an unknown etimology.

Comment: @Charo yes now when you mention it "tabula rasa" is famous concept in philosophy, no? But maybe it was loaned to/from arabic to latin then?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9

Comment: If the information in the above Wiktionary link is correct (that is, that the Arabic word comes from Italian), this is actually a question about Arabic, and I doubt there are here many people that are qualified to answer. Linguistics.SE, perhaps, which includes several question tagged [“arabic”](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic)?

Comment: @DaG weuw, that was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is true that the Italian word *tavola* comes from the Latin *tabŭla* of uncertain origin. But the *Etymological Dictionary of Latin* by Michiel de Vaan can help shed some light into that uncertainty, and at least show that a Semitic origin is unlikely.

According to de Vaan, it comes from an original Proto-Italic form, either **taf* or **taþla*. It has an attested cognate *tafle* in Umbrian ("instrument for transporting the sacrificial fire").

If the Proto-Italic form was **taþla*, it is probably coming from a root **ta-* plus an instrumental suffix **-dʰlo*, with the root coming a from *s*-less **steh₂-* (the origin of the Latin *stāre*, to stand) as in the Proto-Tocharian and Proto-Celtic **tā-* (which also means "to stand").

So, in brief the etymology of *tabŭla* is likely Indoeuropean, cognate of *stāre* (cfr. *stābilis*). Even if this hypothesis is not correct, it will still come from Proto-Italic and so a Semitic loan is very unlikely (especially since the possible Proto-Italic roots look very different from the Arabic word).

---

As Charo said in the comments it seems that the borrowing went in the other direction

> According to [Hans Wehr's 4th edition of *Dictionary of Modern Written Arabic*](http://www.ejtaal.net/aa/#hw4=656,ll=1908,ls=5,la=2630,sg=643,ha=437,br=585,pr=97,aan=360,mgf=549,vi=240,kz=1452,mr=380,mn=836,uqw=987,umr=651,ums=546,umj=488,ulq=1132,uqa=265,uqq=210,bdw=h547,amr=h392,asb=h591,auh=h946,dhq=h337,mht=h548,msb=h146,tla=h68,amj=h480,ens=h1,mis=h1) the Arabic word طاولة comes from the Italian "tavola" -- Charo

Comment: According to [Hans Wehr's 4th edition *Dictionary of Modern Written Arabic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_Modern_Written_Arabic) the Arabic word طاولة comes from the Italian "tavola".

Comment: Here it's the [link](http://www.ejtaal.net/aa/#hw4=656,ll=1908,ls=5,la=2630,sg=643,ha=437,br=585,pr=97,aan=360,mgf=549,vi=240,kz=1452,mr=380,mn=836,uqw=987,umr=651,ums=546,umj=488,ulq=1132,uqa=265,uqq=210,bdw=h547,amr=h392,asb=h591,auh=h946,dhq=h337,mht=h548,msb=h146,tla=h68,amj=h480,ens=h1,mis=h1) to such dictionary. It says: طاولة  (It. *tavola*) ṭāwila ...

Comment: I think this answer gives detailed information and shows the unlikely possibility of an Arabic origin of “tavolo.”

Comment: Mhm, maybe word got transferred from latin or greek via trade during like.. greek golden age or roman empire then..

Comment: @mathreadler Italy and North Africa had extensive commercial contact basically throughout history. Many Arabic words entered Italian that way (for example *ammiraglio*, *divano* etc.) so it's not hard to believe that some Italian words made the same route in the opposite direction

Comment: If the word, as the dictionary says, comes from Italian (rather than Latin), it must have happened quite some time after Roman empire. At the very earliest, around XI century.